# Embedding Strobe Media Player is not working. Is FB blocking further requests of SWF files?

Tags: facebook, embed, embedding

In [this](http://play.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/play/player?player=1&pod=251&layout=22) URL we're using a player developed over Strobe Media Player, which is requesting some extra SWF files (plugins).

The problem is that the player is not being embedded in FB.

The og: video meta tag is http://bo.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/cust/fludev//static/player//audio/current//PlayerStrobe.swf?apiKey=ZrzZGArBbSxqmkFd&contextMenuEnabled=True&campaignId=10&locale=en_US&controlBarAutoHideTimeout=3.0&bufferingOverlay=True&src_flumotioncdn_high=true&controlBarAutoHide=True&height=480&src_flumotioncdn_low=true&player=1&playerId=1&plugins=&plugin_mast=http://bo.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/cust/fludev//static/player//audio/current//MASTPlugin.swf&playButtonOverlay=True&src_flumotioncdn_med=true&autoPlay=False&layout=22&controlBarMode=docked&podId=251&logoPosition1=0&logoPosition2=0&src_flumotioncdn_mobile=true&width=640&backgroundColor=0&src_flumotioncdn_enabled=true&media_type=video&tertiaryColor=16777215&whitelist=[]&src_flumotioncdn_mini=true&autoadvance=False&plugin_flumotioncdn=http://bo.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/cust/fludev//static/player//audio/current//FlumotionCDNPlugin.swf&volume=0.9&language=en_US&src_mast_uri=http://api.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/campaign/10/mast.xml&primaryColor=0&configuration=&name=Standard+video+player&api_referrer=play.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com&is_readonly=False&apiURL=http://api.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/&playerPageURL=http://play.fludev.webtv.flumotion.com/play/?player=1&pod=251&layout=22&src_namespace_mast=http://www.akamai.com/mast/1.0&secondaryColor=16711680&src_flumotioncdn_hd=true&src_namespace_flumotioncdn=http://www.flumotion.com/plugins/flumotioncdn/1.0

Which is working when opened directly in a browser.

Although, when sharing a page with it's og: video meta-tag pointing to the original Strobe Media Player:

http://osmf.org/dev/1.5gm/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?src=http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/strobe/content/test/AFaerysTale_sylviaApostol_640_500_short.flv&autoPlay=false&verbose=true&controlBarAutoHide=false&controlBarPosition=bottom&poster=images/poster.png

It's working. In this case no extra requests are made.

What's the problem? Is FB blocking further requests of SWF files?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try linking to the swf directly and putting everything that follows in Flash Params personally...